# react native currency input

Tags: react-native, expo

anyone has a currency input libary?

I found this but they dont display the UNIT.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-currency-input

```
          <CurrencyInput
            style={styles.productPrice}
            value={price}
            onChangeValue={setPrice}
            unit="$"
            delimiter=","
            separator="."
            precision={2}
            onChangeText={(formattedValue) => {
              console.log(formattedValue); // $2,310.46
            }}
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [React-Number-Format](https://github.com/s-yadav/react-number-format)

Here is a [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/currency-input) for the implementation.

First, install `React-Number-Format`

`npm i react-number-format`

The import it in your file

```
import NumberFormat from 'react-number-format';

...

<NumberFormat thousandSeparator={true} prefix={'$'} />

...
```

Comment: Do you find it useful??